# Cache of links - error

Tags: experience-editor, publishing, links

I have a strange problem with links. On the website I have many components added (one have one link and the other many links). In `Experience Editor` everything works correctly in `Edit` mode. After publishing, or switching to the `Preview` mode, displays the same value for different components in `href` (wrong), but the label is already valid. There may be 5 links with the same `href`, then 3 with another etc.

Has someone met with such behavior?

I use Sitecore 9.1 and GlassMapper.

Comment: Can you add an example of your markup (both from Razor view and the resultant output HTML)?

Comment: Have you added caching to the components and not set the correct vary by?

Answer (score -1):

Check if your HTML structure is correct.

Check for the following errors

1. div tag inside p tag
   `<p>This is a text block <div>but this one is a container</div></p>`
2. Unclosed div tags.